# Elixir: split Genserver tasks across machines

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server, genstage

My Genserver consumer looks like so:

```
defmodule Consumer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link() do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:consumer, :ok, subscribe_to: [Broadcaster]}
  end

  def handle_events(documents, _from, state) do
    for document <- documents do
      Task.async(fn -> Processor.process_document(document) end)
    end
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

  def handle_info({_reference, {_int_state, _msg}}, state) do
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

  def handle_info({:DOWN, _reference, :process, pid, int_state}, state) do
    {:stop, int_state, state}
  end
end
```

I want to "split" `Processor` tasks (i.e., the tasks in `handle_events/3`) across multiple machines if the preceding one is busy, like, waiting for a task to finish. How do I go about doing that?

I've read the [guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html) on distributed tasks, I'm just not sure how to design it so that 1. it splits across machines, and 2. it knows when to split i.e., when it's busy:

```
task = Task.Supervisor.async {Something, :"server@other-machine"}, fn ->
  {:ok, node()}
end
```

I know it involves some arrangement like this but I'm not sure where to start. Anyone have any experience with this kinda thing?

**Update**

The *reason* I need this is that `Processor.process_document(document)` takes ~30 seconds to complete, and only one can be run at a time. Adding a second node capable of taking half the workload essentially halves the processing time.

Comment: This is not possible to answer without some more detail about what your system does and what you expect to gain from this in terms of sidestepping constraints. You can spawn a process on any other node and monitor it the same way you would a local process -- but the more important question is *why* you think you need to do this (memory? CPU time? network bandwidth? etc.). Monitoring host resources is possible. Reporting them is possible. Negotiating task acceptance or delay is also possible. Load shedding or client deference are also possible. What applies to you?

Comment: Totally fair enough. I've added an update that explains my reasoning.

Comment: To clarify... why can only one document be processed at a time? Is there only one system core? Is there an external resource that only accepts a single connection per system? Is there a disk/storage bottleneck?

Comment: It runs a ~30 second script that cannot be processed in parallel.

Comment: Ah, good. We're getting closer. Why can it not be processed in parallel? Can it be processed in parallel on another node or on another host? What you are asking in the question above is essentially "How do I parallelize a task across different physical machines?" so the level at which it can or can't be processed in parallel is important. Without knowing that constraint it is hard to give you an answer other than "use spawn/2,4 and indicate another node". Maybe chat would be a better place to discuss this so we can hash it out at once: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp